# Routing the data from EF .NET Core 6 to Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core-webapi, angular2-routing

I'm trying to get data from my ASP.NET Core 6 back-end to Angular and I run into a problem:

> Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

```
export class EmployeesListComponent {

  employees: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(private employeesService: EmployeesService) {}

  ngOnInit() : void {
      this.employeesService.getAllEmployee()
          .subscribe ({
               next: (employees) => {
                   console.log(employees);
                   this.employees = employees;
               },
               error: (response) => {
                   console.log(response);
               }
          });
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrStu.png)

I use console.log to see the data and it exists

```
<div class="content my-5">
    <h1 class = "mb-3"> Employees </h1>
    <table class="table" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>FirstName </th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>DateOfBirth </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees" >
                <td>{{employee.Id }}</td>
                <td>{{employee.FirstName}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.LastName}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.DateOfBirth}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve it

```
  employees: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(private employeesService: EmployeesService) {}
  ngOnInit():void{
this.employeesService.getAllEmployee()
.subscribe ({
next: (employees:any) =>{
 console.log(employees?.data);

this.employees = employees['data'];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: how it is different from answer given below

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to iterate over an object it should be an array instead .By looking into your console log you can see your data is inside the data property and you need to loop on the data from api instead of the response so changing your component code to

```
this.employeesService.getAllEmployee()
.subscribe ({
  next: (resp) =>{
   console.log(resp.data);
   this.employees = resp.data; //here it should be resp.data
  },
  error: (response) =>{
   console.log(response);
 }
 });
```

should fix the issue